# SyntaxError: invalid syntax in python (unable to run the code)

Tags: python

```
L = ["hello", "good day", "hi", "see you", "ciao", "au revoir"]
L.insert(0, L.pop())
print (L)
list(map(len, L[2::2]) 
print (L)

  File "<ipython-input-90-36e680b90dd3>", line 5
    print (L)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

on running the code I'm getting this error

Answer (score 2):

You have a missing `)` in `list(map(len, L[2::2])`.

It should be `list(map(len, L[2::2]))`